# Xamarin and TabBar in Shell application. Title under the Icon. Why?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I recently updated my Xamarin version (slightly) and decided to rebuild my app. Surprisingly, I see headlines from the other side. Why?!

Before update:
[Title ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwJA1.png)
After update:
[Title under the Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0joX5.png)
Why? :) I want to return everything back without rolling back the updates. Moreover, an empty project from MS works correctly, but I do not find a difference.

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post a basic demo so that we can try to test on our side?

Comment: i solved this problem very simple. Removed all nuget from Android project (by text) and re-install the necessary ones. Thanks.